# C# Backgroundworker with timer

Tags: c#, mysql, timer, backgroundworker, background-process

I wish to run in background an update in MySQL that have to run any 10 seconds defined in `sqlupdateinterval`. Is looks like good, they made an update, but the problem is the time. At a start of the program, he wait first time for the 10 seconds, but after 5-6 updates, the "clock" begin to play crazzy and make updates in lower that 10 second interval. The result is presented here:

```
MariaDB [devel]> select * from mupdate;
+---------+---------+---------------------+
| sensor1 | sensor2 | time                |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
| 154     | 49      | 2020-06-12 10:49:40 |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
MariaDB [devel]> select * from mupdate;
+---------+---------+---------------------+
| sensor1 | sensor2 | time                |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
| 138     | 112     | 2020-06-12 10:49:41 |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
MariaDB [devel]> select * from mupdate;
+---------+---------+---------------------+
| sensor1 | sensor2 | time                |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
| 130     | 47      | 2020-06-12 10:49:47 |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
MariaDB [devel]> select * from mupdate;
+---------+---------+---------------------+
| sensor1 | sensor2 | time                |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
| 38      | 112     | 2020-06-12 10:49:48 |
+---------+---------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Have an `Invoke`, inside i call a `MySQLUpdate(sensor1, sensor2);`  that looks so:

```
private void MySQLUpdate(string sensor1, string sensor2)
        {
            if (!backgroundWorker2.IsBusy)
            {
                string[] MySQLUpdateSensors = { sensor1, sensor2 };
                backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync(MySQLUpdateSensors);
            }
            else
            {
                MySQLUpdateisExecuted = true;
            }

        }
```

The `backgroundWorker2` looks so:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                //Define sensors
                string[] MySQLUpdateSensors = (string[])e.Argument;
                string sensor1 = MySQLUpdateSensors[0];
                string sensor2 = MySQLUpdateSensors[1];
                //MySQLUpdate
                if (sqlupdateenabled == "Y" && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlupdateinterval) && sqlupdatetype == "MySQL/MariaDB" && MySQLUpdateisExecuted == false)
                {
                    MySQLUpdateisExecuted = true;
                    System.Timers.Timer MyUpdateTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    MyUpdateTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MySQLUpdateOnTimedEvent);
                    MyUpdateTimer.Interval = 1000 * Convert.ToInt32(sqlupdateinterval);
                    MyUpdateTimer.Enabled = true;
                    string connectionString = "SERVER=" + sqlupdateserver + ";" + "PORT=" + sqlupdateport + ";" + "DATABASE=" + sqlupdatedatabase + ";" + "UID=" + sqlupdateusername + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + sqlupdatepassword + ";";
                    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        string MySQLUpdateQuery = "UPDATE " + sqlupdatetable + " SET sensor1='" + sensor1 + "', sensor2='" + sensor2 + "', time = NOW();";
                        MySqlCommand cmdMySQLUpdate = new MySqlCommand(MySQLUpdateQuery, connection);
                        cmdMySQLUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                    }
                }

            }));
        }
```

The `MySQLUpdateOnTimedEvent` looks so:

```
private void MySQLUpdateOnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            MySQLUpdateisExecuted = false;
        }
```

How to achieve that a clock wait 10 seconds and after this update the `MySQLUpdateisExecuted`  to `false` so that by next running, he start again the update after 10 seconds? Why have i this behaviuor?

Comment: Where is the updateInterval defined?

Comment: Is defined on beginning with: `private string sqlupdateinterval = string.Empty;` and later is populated in Form1_Load from registry. Have checked, is correctly populated, and contain `10` Even if a change to `MyUpdateTimer.Interval = 10000;` i have the same behavior.

Comment: May be your update is taking more time than expected. When I work with timers I stop the timer before doing the timer's job and start the timer again when the job is done. If the job takes more time than the interval, the timer events are overlapped, if you have transaction in the timer's job It can lock tables and the overlaped event can not do the job or must wait the lock will be released.
This can be the cause than the execution of the jobs dont run in the same time interval.

Comment: Have added `MyUpdateTimer.Stop();` before `string connectionString` and `MyUpdateTimer.Start();` after `connection.Close();` but have not helped, have the same behavior.

Comment: Have you check the time that the job is taking?

Comment: No, how to do this?

Comment: Have you check the time that the job is taking? Reading your code, seams that your timer only set MySQLUpdateisExecuted to false. This dont grant the lapse time between executions, This grant that every 10 seg the variable MySQLUpdateisExecuted will be set to false, the execution time if affected by when this value will be checked. If it is not checked faster than 10 second the time lapse can be diferent every time.

Comment: set a variable at the begining of the job code with the timestamp, and compare it with the timestamp at the end of the job. You will get the durationg with the difference between this two timestamps

Comment: I would move the job to a function and I would call it from the timer event. Move the timer into the background service.

Comment: Have try this now also, but no lucky.